# Vue prevent blur event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, blur, onblur

I have an editable input component, which has an `isEditable` state.

By clicking outside the input field, I use `@blur` event.
By clicking on the enter key, I trigger another event.

Both methods use the same logic, and after the logic finishes, I set the `isEditable` to `false`. In this case, somehow the blur event is triggered. (I guess because the input field disappears (I guess because it uses `v-if="isEditable"`).
Is there any way to prevent blur to be triggered by changing the state programatically?

Comment: I dont see how changing programatically the state of isEditable would prevent the blur event to be triggered.
Please post a simplified jsfiddle of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If hiding the div activates the blur event, then you can just make the keypress Enter event hide the div, your logic will be executed only once in both cases.

Before :

```
@blur="myLogic"
@keyup.enter="myLogic"
```

After :

```
@blur="myLogic"
@keyup.enter="willActivateBlur"

// methods

willActivateBlur: function() {
  this.isEditable = false
}
```

Edit : Wait, did you say "click on the enter key" ?... I got confused, are you clicking or pressing a key ?
If your problem is using @blur and @click at the same time, a lot of questions were asked about this already, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313603/vuejs-on-blur-for-custom-select-element-not-working).